# IdentityServer different Tenants/Users across browser tabs

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identityserver3

We're using IdentityServer for authentication in our SaaS product, which has many tenants, and our users may have access to multiple tenants.  We use oidc-client from a VueJs front-end to auth with IdentityServer and then call aspnet webapis.

Currently we have a custom IProfileService that augments claims (ex. a TenantId) based on an acr_value passed in during auth.

**The Problem:**  If a user opens our app in two different browser tabs with different tenants, the Token Renewal flow will fight (basically snaps to the last tenant that the user switched to).

I think this is because it considers each user/tenant combo a different User and IdentityServer only supports a single user per session (and session is shared between browser tabs)?

Can anyone confirm?  Is my only option to make the token non-tenant-specific? Or are there reasonable ways to accomplish this?

Comment: You're either using IdSrv 3 or 4, use the correct tags please.

Comment: As for your actual question: it looks like you're either using cookies (and they are shared within a browser) or localstorage/sessionstorage from the UI to store the token. If any of those is true, well, that's the problem, you're sharing the token, and at one point one will survive and the other die

Comment: Is there an alternate option that keeps the tabs isolated from each other??

Comment: @AndyV So, you want different users be able to login in different tabs? If so this can be done but the implementation depends on your use case which is not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes, different tabs should be isolated and not "share" user/login state in any way.  What additional context do you need?  
I noted above we're using oidc-client w/ a VueJs front-end, IdentityServer, and webapi.  Happy to provide more detail if needed.

Comment: @LalitaCode any thoughts on the above ^ ?  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyV I totally missed your comment. The problem is the Auth cookie set by the Identity Server, if I remember correctly. You will get authorized even though you keep the Access token in the session, isolating it from other tabs. This will be easily solved if you separate tenants by subdomain.

Comment: @AndyV Even if you don't want to separate tenant by subdomain, you can still achieve what you want just by using different Auth url for each tenant. So, for tenant1 your Auth server url will be tenant1.auth.com .This way the cookie will be set with the subdomain, and different tenant can call their "own" auth server accordingly. I have stopped working with Identity Server so, I havent tried it out.

Comment: @AndyV Some relevant info to my above comment is here on my blog https://jayantarimal.com.np/implement-domain-or-subdomain-based-multi-tenancy-in-identity-server/ . You just need IDS4 with subdomain binding, so that each tenant can call IDS4 with its own relevant subdomain binding. You will achieve something like this https://streamable.com/z5apun . Note that I have used separate subdomain for each tenant which is not needed in your case.